# No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of ‘floor’

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a Haskell function that calculates x mod y:

```
fmod :: Double -> Double -> Double
fmod x y = x - y*m
    where m = floor a
          a = x / y
```

Running this in stack yields:

`` No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of `floor' ``

Comment: The return type of a `floor` is an `Integral` type, a `Double` is not an `Integral` type.

Comment: I'm a haskell newbie, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of a [**`floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor) is an [**`Integral`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) type, a `Double` is not an `Integral` type, so the `m` in your code can not be a `Double`, this is important, since the [**`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-) and [**`(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-45-) functions return the same type as both operands.

You can however make use of [**`fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) to convert an `Integer` to any `Num` type. So you can work with:

```
fmod :: Double -> Double -> Double
fmod x y = x - y * fromInteger (floor (x / y))
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I thought the problem was in the argument of floor. Haskell needs better hints.

Comment: IMO it's plain silly that `floor`, `round` and `ceiling` have an `Integral` constraint – the only thing that accomplishes is perhaps documentation that the result will indeed be integral. The signature could just as well be `(RealFrac a, Num b) => a -> b`. (That's not to say I'm generally in favour of making signatures as general as they can possibly be – but in that case it would definitely make sense.)